# chrome remote desktop gives "Failed to start host service" error

Tags: debian, chrome, remote-desktop

I am trying to "Enable Remote Connections" after installing the chrome web app as well as the chrome remote desktop service as per the following article:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en

I am trying to get it working on Debian Jessie. After installation, it seemed to work briefly. i was able to RDP into my Linux box from my Mac. But after a reboot of my Linux machine, i kept getting the following error:

Failed to start host service

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely not related to your problem due to you saying it briefly works, but I got the same error from mistakenly creating the .desktop file in home as the root user, so it was inaccessible, took me ages to work this out...